# Turning mud to solid ground

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

What cantrip, if any, would be able to turn mud into solid ground? Would mold earth work? Would shape water?

Context: I'm making a homebrew race who live in an area of bog, and I thought it would be interesting to have them making their own homes with racial spellcasting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Mold Earth works...

From [DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mold-earth),

> If the dirt or stone you target is on the ground, you cause it to become difficult terrain. Alternatively, you can cause the ground to become normal terrain if it is already difficult terrain. This change lasts for 1 hour.

The [difficult terrain](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Movement#content) description includes deep swamps, so Mold Earth could turn a small section bog into habitable ground.

#### ...on a small patch of ground...

Unfortunately, you'd need each member of a household able to cast this cantrip, as...

> If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have no more than two of its non-instantaneous effects active at a time

#### ...for an hour

In the long term, your inhabitants will need a solution that doesn't involve near-constant re-upping of cantrip durations. While certain spells such as [Private Sanctum](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Private%20Sanctum#content) gain a permanent duration with repeated casting, Mold Earth isn't one of them.

Though not directly addressed in the rules, a few [Survival](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#UsingEachAbility)-savvy individuals could (at the DM's discretion) devise longer-term solutions, such as diverting a river that feeds into said bog, or digging down to bedrock and creating a foundation to prevent seepage into a patch of ground.  Ultimately, this looks like a job for craftsmen or a mid-level caster judiciously using [Wall of Stone](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wall%20of%20Stone#content)

Comment: I think you're ignoring an important part of the spell description: "*If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have no more than two of its non-instantaneous effects active at a time*".

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right.  Fixing it

Comment: I'm having fun imagining the mutual recriminations flying when the schedules get mixed up and no one ends up casting that hour's Mold Earth on a particular square, leading to, at best, a partially sunken building, and more likely, a partially collapsed or fallen over building. Months of effort spent building, undone by even a six second delay in reupping the spells.